# Python - Converting PNG/JPG image to best form for MNIST digit classification

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, mnist

I am creating a program that converts an Image(from UI) to MNIST array and then predict that digit.
There is nothing wrong in model , I hope, as its predictions are most of the times accurate when testing MNIST image that was provided from data set. But the prediction is poor when I use my image and convert it to MNIST array

```
def imageprepare(argv):
    im = PIL.Image.open(argv).convert('L')
    width = float(im.size[0])
    height = float(im.size[1])
    newImage = PIL.Image.new('L', (28, 28), (255))  # creates white canvas of 28x28 pixels#28 28

    if width > height:  # check which dimension is bigger
        # Width is bigger. Width becomes 20 pixels.
        nheight = int(round((20.0 / width * height), 0))  # resize height according to ratio width
        if (nheight == 0):  # rare case but minimum is 1 pixel
            nheight = 1
            # resize and sharpen
        img = im.resize((20, nheight), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS).filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN)
        wtop = int(round(((28 - nheight) / 2), 0))  # calculate horizontal position
        newImage.paste(img, (4, wtop))  # paste resized image on white canvas
    else:
        # Height is bigger. Heigth becomes 20 pixels.
        nwidth = int(round((20.0 / height * width), 0))  # resize width according to ratio height
        if (nwidth == 0):  # rare case but minimum is 1 pixel
            nwidth = 1
            # resize and sharpen
        img = im.resize((nwidth, 20), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS).filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN)
        wleft = int(round(((28 - nwidth) / 2), 0))  # caculate vertical pozition
        newImage.paste(img, (wleft, 4))  # paste resized image on white canvas
    tv = list(newImage.getdata())  # get pixel values
    # normalize pixels to 0 and 1. 0 is pure white, 1 is pure black.
    tva = [(255 - x) * 1.0 / 255.0 for x in tv]
    return tva
```

and here is the code that I have used for user interface (mouse as paint brush to enter a digit)(convertToPNG() is used for tranparent background)

```
def paint(event):
    x1, y1 = (event.x - 1), (event.y - 1)
    x2, y2 = (event.x + 1), (event.y + 1)
    cv.create_oval(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="black",width=15)
    draw.line([x1, y1, x2, y2],fill="black",width=15)


def convertToPNG():
    img = PIL.Image.open('./image.png')
    img = img.convert("RGBA")
    datas = img.getdata()
    newData = []
    for item in datas:
        if item[0] == 255 and item[1] == 255 and item[2] == 255:
            newData.append((255, 255, 255, 0))
        else:
            newData.append(item)

    img.putdata(newData)
    img.save("./image.png", "PNG")

root = Tk()
cv = Canvas(root, width=width, height=height, bg='white')
cv.pack()
image1 = PIL.Image.new("RGB", (width, height), white)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image1)
cv.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
cv.bind("<B1-Motion>", paint)
button=Button(text="SaveImage",command=save)
button.pack()
button2=Button(text="StartLearning",command=startLearning)
button2.pack()
root.mainloop()
```